# How can i set the 1st column data type as int and float for all the rest of columns?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to set the 1st column 'ID' as index using numpy only.

```
import numpy as np
import io
from numpy import genfromtxt

data =io.StringIO("""
ID,1,2,3,4,5,6
5362,0.974,-0.404,-0.763,0.868,-0.5,0.16
485,-0.659,0.531,0.623,0.402,0.772,0.506
582,0.045,0.994,0.762,-0.036,0.117,-0.355
99,0.777,0.537,0.391,0.456,0.329,0.108
75,-0.44,0.522,0.856,-0.04,0.656,-0.935
474,0.357,0.81,0.135,0.389,0.055,0.224
594,-0.291,0.031,0.742,-0.332,0.815,0.983
597,0.968,-0.357,0.591,0.892,0.375,0.88
124,0.737,0.611,0.764,0.289,0.298,-0.705
635,0.883,0.96,-0.987,0.29,0.997,0.186
7894,-0.045,0.047,0.523,0.068,-0.9,0.356
1268,0.561,0.736,-0.375,0.465,0.908,0.2
38,0.465,0.623,0.734,0.145,0.489,0.759
88,0.029,0.166,0.098,0.285,0.18,0.829
887,0.464,0.652,-0.896,0.07,0.772,-0.268
994,-0.611,0.986,0.708,-0.195,0.938,0.166
478,0.109,0.664,0.977,0.2,-0.466,0.676
693,0.893,0.536,0.827,0,0.658,-0.31
455,0.745,0.851,0.025,0.667,0.094,0.127
874,0.036,-0.212,0.879,0.966,0.788,0.719
""")
```

I have used `skip_header=1` but still I am geting the 1st row in my data.So  I have tried the foll.

```
data = genfromtxt(data, delimiter=',', skip_header=1, dtype=np.float64)
data = np.delete(data, 0, axis = 0)
#Suppose
N=7
```

Here I want to take the 1st N rows and find the determinant and show the corresponding indexes of the 7 rows as integers.
I

```
X = data[1:N+1, 1:]
det_X = np.linalg.det(X.T@X)
```

Expected : But as Integer values instead of float

```
[[5362.]
 [ 485.]
 [ 582.]
 [  99.]
 [  75.]
 [ 474.]
 [ 594.]]
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting ? or what your expecting ?

Comment: How can I get the corresponding values from 1st column for my X array?

Comment: Use `usecols` to read the first column and the rest separately.  Alternatively you could use a compound dtype to make structured array, but I think loading two separate arrays would be simpler to do and use.

Comment: @hpaulj - So do I need to put 1st column in another array? Like ```X_ID = data[:N,:1]```

Comment: you can put it in a separate array 

idx = data[1:N+1,:1].astype("uint16")

Comment: @venkatakrishnan - Yes that is as expected.